# show that $\prod_{1\leq x<y\leq (p-1)/2 }(x^2+y^2)\equiv (-1)^{\lfloor (p+1)/8\rfloor}\mod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, determinant

> Let $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ be a prime. Show that $\prod_{1\leq x<y\leq (p-1)/2 }(x^2+y^2)\equiv (-1)^{\lfloor (p+1)/8\rfloor}\pmod p$.

Since $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, there is no "square root" of $-1$ modulo p. Also since p is prime the number of quadratic residues modulo p is $(p-1)/2$. I know that there is a primitive root modulo p (this is well known). Let $a$ be a primitive root and set $x=a^2$. Then each term $k^2$ where $1\leq k\leq (p-1)/2$ equals $a^{2i}$ for some $1\leq i\leq (p-1)$. Observe that $2i$ is equivalent to an even number modulo $p-1$ as $p-1$ is even, and so we may write $a^{2i} = a^{2k}$ for some $1\leq k\leq (p-1)/2$. Thus, the product on the left is just $\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq (p-1)/2} (x^i + x^j)$. It might be useful to recall that the Vandermonde determinant of the matrix whose ith row is $(1,a_i, a_i^2,\cdots, a_i^{n-1})$, where $a_1,\cdots, a_n$ are distinct real numbers, equals $\prod_{1\leq i < j\leq n} (a_j-a_i).$ In particular, since $x^i\not\equiv x^j\mod p$ for $1\leq i < j\leq (p-1)/2,$ we can set $a_i = x^i$ for $1\leq i\leq (p-1)/2,$ set $n=(p-1)/2$ and consider an $n\times n$ Vandermonde matrix. But I'm not sure how to use this Vandermonde matrix to solve the problem.

Comment: Iirc this is a putnam problem some time last decade.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the product $\prod_{1\leq a<b\leq \frac{p-1}{2}}\,\left(a^2+b^2\right)$, where $p$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2839396/11619).

Comment: @dezdichado Miklos Schweitzer competition problem from 1962.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, ah I see. I got it confused with Putnam 2012 B6 where at some point you compute:
$$\prod\limits_{0\leq x < y\leq p-1}(x^2+xy+y^2)$$